# Error 2207: parameter child non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have following code in flash as3 but when I compiled to swf and clicks one of buttons that goes back to the options page from gameover screen, the errors came up like this:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at FourSeasonsOfElements_v47_fla::MainTimeline/removeWinterScene()
    at FourSeasonsOfElements_v47_fla::MainTimeline/playAgain()
```

The code in frame 3 (gameover screen) is:

```
playagainbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAgain);
function playAgain(event:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop("options");
    removeWinterScene();
    removeAutumnScene();
    removeSummerScene();
    MovieClip(root).gameTime = 0;//reset time
}
```

action in long keyframe from 1 to 7  timeline:

```
function removeWinterScene(){
    MovieClip(root).removeChild(winterbg);
    MovieClip(root).removeChild(shadebg1);
    MovieClip(root).removeChild(winterHeading);
}
```

the winter game scene frame in other frame 7 has the code in the timeline:

```
stop();
var winterbg:WinterScene = new WinterScene();
var shadebg1:fadeShade = new fadeShade();

var winterHeading:WinterSeasonTitle = new WinterSeasonTitle();
addChildAt(winterbg,0);//move the winter background in the background.
addChildAt(shadebg1,1);
addChildAt(winterHeading,1);

winterHeading.x = 200;
```

Any assistance on the resolution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is complaining that you're trying to execute removeChild(null). That means that the child is either already removed, or your code has lost/never had a reference to it. Without seeing more of the surrounding code it's difficult to know the right answer, but here are some relevant questions to help you investigate.

Are you sure you have a reference to the object you're trying to remove (does the variable point to the correct object)? Is the object already removed/garbage collected (for example, because the movieclip has moved to another frame)? Is the variable local, which means you don't have access to it from other objects/functions?

Comment: In regards to your question, the code tries to remove the movie clip instances located in the different or other frames, for example, the code is in the frame 7 tries to find the movie clip that is dynamically generated in frame 2. I was wondering if that is the scope problem.

Comment: When you move to a different frame, flash automatically removes the children no longer present in the new frame (and then re-creates them again if you go back). If there are no listeners or other references to the removed object, it will get garbage collected eventually.

Comment: Thanks @jpop so does that mean I have to use class to access and perform action locally in the same frame?

Comment: As a general rule, I would say that it's best to separate your code from the movieclips. Put all your code in a class in frame 1 of the main movieclip, and then run things from there, That way you'll avoid the scope problems and have a much easier time managing things.